# Hotplug Device Driver Priority

Tags: drivers, devices, usb-drive, hot-plug

Is it possible to have more than one driver for one purpose (eg. USB) included in the Linux kernel?

If so, then how does the kernel decide which one to load?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are asking. You mean you have two USB keyboard drivers? Please clarify your question.

Comment: yes let's suppose I have two drivers how the kernel decides which one to use?

Comment: AFAIK it is impossible to have two different drivers for one purpose in the Linux kernel.

Comment: yes it is impossible to have both controlling the device but you can have both loaded/registered to the kernel so I wanna know how does the kernel decide